# Error when using source of Servicestack instead of dll

Tags: reflection, servicestack

I'm trying to use the source of the ServiceStack framework to get a real grasp of how the authentication works instead of following the source code.

I started by cloning the master rep of ServiceStack and adding the csproj of ServiceInterface to my solution. I then removed the ServiceStack.ServiceInterface dll and added the local project. Due to dependencies I added also to my solution the projects: ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Common, ServiceStack.Interfaces, ServiceStack.OrmLite and ServiceStack.OrmLite.

If I add the plugin AuthFeature I get the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.AuthFeature..ctor(System.Func`1<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthSession>, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthProvider[])'.
```

I think that the reflection method cannot find the constructor of the class, but the class in the source has the constructor `public AuthFeature(Func<IAuthSession> sessionFactory, IAuthProvider[] authProviders, string htmlRedirect = "~/login")` that I believe it matches the signature of the missing method error.

The version of the working dll version is 3.9.43 from Nuget.
I can provide more details if needed.